# Callback function from rust to go

Tags: go, rust, ffi, cgo

I am trying to create the possibility to call a Rust function from Go and then said rust function makes a function call back to Go. I use CGO as an FFI interface between Go and Rust.
The following is my Go code (src/main.go):

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./../lib
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./../bin -lgo_move -Wl,-rpath=./bin
#include "move.h"
*/

//export cosmosCallbackWrapper
func cosmosCallbackWrapper(data *C.uchar, dataLen C.int) {
    // Convert data to Go slice
    goData := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(data), dataLen)

    // Call the actual callback function
    cosmosCallback(goData)
}

// SetCosmosCallback sets the callback function to be called by the Move VM.
func SetCosmosCallback(callback func([]byte)) {
    cosmosCallback = callback
    C.set_cosmos_callback((C.cosmos_callback)(unsafe.Pointer(C.cosmosCallbackWrapper)))
}

var cosmosCallback func([]byte)

func main() {
    // Create a new Move interpreter

    // Set the callback function
    SetCosmosCallback(func(data []byte) {
        fmt.Println("Received data from Move VM:", data)
        // Handle data and call Cosmos SDK functions as needed
    })
}
```

This is my Rust code (src/lib.rs)

```
use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_int};
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::sync::Mutex;
#[macro_use] extern crate lazy_static;
pub fn main() {
}
pub type CosmosCallback = extern "C" fn(*const c_char, c_int);

lazy_static! {
        static ref CALLBACK: Mutex<Option<CosmosCallback>> = Mutex::new(None);
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn set_cosmos_callback(callback: CosmosCallback) {
        let mut cb = CALLBACK.lock().unwrap();
        *cb = Some(callback);
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn cosmosCallbackWrapper(data: *const c_char, data_len: c_int) {
    let cb = CALLBACK.lock().unwrap();
    if let Some(callback) = &*cb {
        callback(data, data_len);
    }
}
```

This is my Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "go-move"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"


[workspace]
members = [    ".",]
```

This is lib/move.h (the header file for the shared lib):

```
#ifndef MOVE_VM_LIB_H
#define MOVE_VM_LIB_H

#include <stdint.h>
//typedef void (*cosmos_callback)(const unsigned char *data, int data_len);
//void set_cosmos_callback(cosmos_callback callback);

typedef void (*cosmos_callback)(const uint8_t* data, int32_t data_len);

void set_cosmos_callback(cosmos_callback callback);
#endif
```

And this is my Makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
.PHONY: build
OS = $(shell uname)
clean:
        rm -rf bin
        rm -rf target
build:
        @echo The OS is $(OS)
        mkdir bin
        cargo build --release
ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
        cp target/release/libgo_move.so bin/
else
        cp target/release/libgo_move.dylib bin/
endif
        cp -a lib/. bin/
        go build --ldflags="-L./bin -lgo_move" -o bin/main src/main.go
run:
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./bin && ./main
```

The File structure is as follows:

```
src
    main.go
    main.rs
bin
    libgo_move.so (after cargo build)
lib
    move.h
Cargo.toml
Makefile
```

After running `make clean build`, I am getting the following output:

```
cp target/release/libgo_move.so bin/
cp -a lib/. bin/
go build -o bin/main  src/main.go
# command-line-arguments
src/main.go:27:59: could not determine kind of name for C.cosmosCallbackWrapper
src/main.go:27:25: could not determine kind of name for C.cosmos_callback
src/main.go:27:2: could not determine kind of name for C.set_cosmos_callback
```

For some reason, it cant find the the ffi functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./../lib
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./../bin -lgo_move -Wl,-rpath=./bin
#include "move.h"
*/
```

has to go prior to the imports. That's all it was.